Use enum as const type parameter
I know you cannot use an enum as a const type parameter in Rust currently. In particular this doesn't compile:
struct Foo<const F: Fruit = { Fruit::Apple }> {
    ...
}

Only integers, char and bool can be used.
So what is the idiomatic way to get around this, where you would like to use an enum but can't?
This compiles but fails to enforce that users only provide a u8 corresponding to an enum variant.
struct Foo<const A: u8 = { Fruit::Apple as u8 }> {
    data: u32,
}
impl Foo<{ Fruit::Apple as u8 }> {
    fn bar(&self) -> u32 {
        42
    }
}


Use a sealed trait.
You cannot, today, constrain a generic parameter to values of a user-written type, but you constrain a generic parameter to only types implementing a specific trait, and make the trait unimplementable by anyone else than you.
A sealed trait is a public trait, with a private super trait -- a "hole" of sort in the accessibility checks, that has been found too useful to get rid of:
mod sealed { pub(super) trait Sealed {} }

pub trait Fruity: sealed::Sealed {
    const FRUIT: Fruit;
}

Then you need to implement Fruity (and Sealed) on a bunch of separate types, for each enum value:
#[allow(private_bounds)]
pub trait Fruity: sealed::Sealed {
    const FRUIT: Fruit;
}

macro_rules! impl_fruity {
    ($fruit:ident) => {
        pub struct $fruit;
    
        impl sealed::Sealed for $fruit {}
        
        impl Fruity for $fruit {
            const FRUIT: Fruit = Fruit::$fruit;
        }
    }
}

impl_fruity!(Apple);
impl_fruity!(Banana);

And from there, you can take a Fruity as a generic parameter.
You'll need nightly to use the associated constant at compile-time, though:
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]
#![allow(incomplete_features)]

struct Foo<T: Fruity>
where
    [(); T::FRUIT as u8 as usize]: Sized,
{
    data: [u8; T::FRUIT as u8 as usize],
}

impl<T: Fruity> Default for Foo<T> 
where
    [(); T::FRUIT as u8 as usize]: Sized,
{
    fn default() -> Self {
        let data = [0; T::FRUIT as u8 as usize];
        
        Self { data }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo: Foo<Banana> = Foo::default();
    
    println!("{:?}", foo.data);
}

Note: it's not strictly necessary to write Sized after the [(); T::FRUIT as u8 as usize]: part... but the bounds always feel incomplete to me without an actual bound, so I use Sized since it always works.
If using the associated constant at compile-time is not necessary, then the solution works on stable:
struct Foo<T: Fruity> {
    data: [u8; 2],
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<fn(T)->T>,
}

impl<T: Fruity> Default for Foo<T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        let data = Default::default();
        let _marker = std::marker::PhantomData;
        
        Self { data, _marker }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo: Foo<Banana> = Foo::default();
    
    println!("{:?}", foo.data);
}

Note: the weird fn(T)->T in PhantomData is to ensure that T is invariant -- neither co-variant nor contra-variant -- without declaring that the type "owns" a T, which would affect auto-trait implementations such as Send or Sync.

I think that another workaround can be simply declaring (module-spec) global constants, i.e., using module with pub const.
A minimal working code should be intutive to new-commers newcomers of rust:
pub mod Fruit {
    #![allow(non_snake_case)]
    #![allow(non_upper_case_globals)]
    pub type FruitType = u8;
    pub const Apple: FruitType = 0;
    pub const Banana: FruitType = 1;
}
use Fruit::*;

struct Foo<const A: FruitType> {}

pub trait Bar {
    fn bar(&self) -> u32;
}

impl Bar for Foo<Apple> {
    fn bar(&self) -> u32 {
        42
    }
}

impl Bar for Foo<Banana> {
    fn bar(&self) -> u32 {
        84
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::<Apple> {};
    assert_eq!(foo.bar(), 42);
    let foo = Foo::<Banana> {};
    assert_eq!(foo.bar(), 84);
}

Assertions to this problem

We are not considering advanced enum (for rust, types and objects can be embedded into enum; but we are not discussing this topic).
I'm not sure whether it is idiomatic way. But I'm seriously considering to use this workaround in my project.

Pros

No nightly features.
No advanced trait concepts involved.
Foo::<Apple> instead of Foo::<{ Apple as u8 }> (though if Apple is not directly imported, curly brackets is still required for Foo::<{ Fruit::Apple }>).

Cons

Now Fruit is a module, but not enum or struct. If you wish that Fruit has some member functions or trait implementations, that's not possible in this workaround.
You may explicitly define every constant values in this workaround. For enum, that's automatically done; you may not explicitly define Apple = 0 and Banana = 1 when using enum.

Applicable Scenario

When nightly rust is not available;
When constant values (Apple, Banana) are used like flags, and not treating enum as object (Fruit does not need to have member functions, trait implementations, etc.).
When bitwise operations on flags is not an important feature to this task.

